# Converting a stream to bool doesn't work on another compiler

Tags: c++

Why with [libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f5e934eba8cd7b6) this works but with [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7829236b9500ad6) it fails? On gcc it also works:

```
bool b = std::cin;
```

Comment: In C++11 you must use `bool b = static_cast<bool>(std::cin);`

Comment: @NeilKirk That works in GCC but only because of the implicit conversion to `void*` and then to `bool`. But for clang it works if I take away `-stdlib=xxx` or if I use `-stdlib=libstdc++` but it doesn't work on `libc++` even in c++1y mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the language standard and compiler you compile with.

Until C++11, `std::basic_ios` had `operator void*`, since C++11 it has `explicit operator bool` instead.

The second one is explicit, meaning an implicit conversion like in your example cannot use it.

libstdc++ from the GNU project still unconditionally contains the pre-C++ conversion (Version 4.9.1):

```
operator void*() const
{ return this->fail() ? 0 : const_cast<basic_ios*>(this); }
```

The bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56193 is RESOLVED-FIXED since 2014-09-24, so the next release should be corrected.

Comment: I'm just doing it on Coliru and the gcc version is 4.9 and clang is 3.5.

Comment: So what does your answer mean about why there is different behavior? Aren't libstdc++ and libc++ both supposed to be up-to-date because I'm using the latest compiler versions?

Comment: Seems libstdc++ just is not up to C++11 there.

Comment: When I take away `-stdlib=xxx` away completely, what library does it use?

Comment: The systems standard-library, so libstdc++ on Linux.

Comment: Are there different libraries than `libstdc++` or `libc++` that I can use?

Comment: Yes, depending on the target system. Dinkumware (MS), SGI, HP, maybe more. But unless you have a good reason, stay with the CLANG or GCC one (prefer the system standard one). (CLANG is more modern and standards-conformant)

Comment: Thanks, last one: Why can't I use `-stdlib=xxx` in gcc?

Comment: Not implemented... https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (13.3.1.5 Initialization by conversion function, p.#1)

> The conversion functions of S and its base classes are considered.
>   Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within S
>   and yield type T or a type that can be converted to type T via a
>   standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) are candidate functions. For
>   direct-initialization, those explicit conversion functions that are
>   not hidden within S and yield type T or a type that can be converted
>   to type T with a qualification conversion (4.4) are also candidate
>   functions.

Class `std::basic_ios` has explicit conversion function `operator bool`. As
this declaration

```
bool b = std::cin;
```

does not use the direct initialization (there is the copy initialization) then it seems it is a bug of the compiler, that is the declaration shall not be compiled.